# why the attribute of instances cannot be recognized by lambda?

Tags: python

I create five lists for storing instances satisfying a certain condition and I intend to sort them by the instances attribute "hours". I can read the attribute outside the loop and run this line seperately and there is no error. However I run the block, the results say that the attributes don't exist. What causes that? How can I solve it?

```
  File "F:/Aalto study/semester3/programming/Project_studyplan.py", line 143, in print_course
    courselist.sort(key = lambda x: x.hours[0])
  File "F:/Aalto study/semester3/programming/Project_studyplan.py", line 143, in <lambda>
    courselist.sort(key = lambda x: x.hours[0])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'hours'
```

WOrkbook trace:

```
In [196]: courselist[0].hours
Out[196]: (9, 10)

In [199]:courselist.sort(key = lambda x: x.hours)
In [200]:courselist.sort(key = lambda x: x.hours[0])
```

Code:

```
    courselist = [[] for _ in range(5)]
    for selected in self.course:
        if given_period == selected.period:
            course_n += 1
            courselist[selected.weekday-1].append(selected)
    courselist.sort(key = lambda x: x.hours[0])
```

Thanks to all's answer and advice, I found where the problem is and solve it completely. :)

Comment: Your `courselist` is a list of lists, so `x` in your lambda is one of those sublists.

Comment: The elements of `courselist` are lists. So when you use `key=lambda x: x.hours[0]` then `x` is a list and a list doesn't have an attribute `hours`.

Comment: @John AndersonCan you see my update? It is weird that this line can be run solely but cannot be run in block.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `courselist.sort(key = lambda x: x[0].hours)` ?

Comment: We can't answer this, since you have not included your actual data. What's the content of `courselist` when you sort it? We can't know that, without knowing what `self` and `given_period` are. Are you sure all items in `courselist` are the same type? Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Obviously the `courselist` in your workbooke example is not the same as in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
courselist = [[] for _ in range(5)]
...
courselist.sort(key = lambda x: x.hours[0])
```

Each element of `courselist` is a list.  Therefore, each `x` in your lambda expression is one of those lists.  A `list` does not have an attribute `hours`: that's apparently an attribute of a `course`.  You need to look inside those lists to find the courses.

We can't **fix** your code, since you failed to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to sort the 5 sublists in `courselist`, but your code attempts to sort `courselist` itself. Since the objects inside `courselist` are lists, they don't have an attribute called `hours`. Presumably, your `selected` objects do. So instead, sort each sublist individually:

```
for day in courselist:
    day.sort(key = lambda x: x.hours[0])
```

(I can't test that this is fully correct for your code, as you haven't provided a complete example.)

Answer (score 0):

In line 143, the error is in the line

```
courselist.sort(key = lambda x: x.hours[0])
```

More precisely, in `x.hours`. x is a list. As I have no idea what hours should be, I cannot fix it. Lists are accessed via index (a non-negative integer)